Glb skinning object export issue
skinning object already its under parent of amateur bone. While exporting to glb and see in babylonjs viewer skinned object is outside of root node. is that any solution to fix the issue. also i checked glb viewer.Its show some error.
NODE_SKINNED_MESH_NON_ROOT  Node with a skinned mesh is not root. Parent transforms will not affect a skinned mesh. /nodes/31
NODE_SKINNED_MESH_NON_ROOT  Node with a skinned mesh is not root. Parent transforms will not affect a skinned mesh. /nodes/93
NODE_SKINNED_MESH_NON_ROOT  Node with a skinned mesh is not root. Parent transforms will not affect a skinned mesh. /nodes/95
NODE_SKINNED_MESH_NON_ROOT  Node with a skinned mesh is not root. Parent transforms will not affect a skinned mesh. /nodes/156
NODE_SKINNED_MESH_NON_ROOT  Node with a skinned mesh is not root. Parent transforms will not affect a skinned mesh. /nodes/158
NODE_SKINNED_MESH_NON_ROOT  Node with a skinned mesh is not root. Parent transforms will not affect a skinned mesh. /nodes/226
NODE_SKINNED_MESH_NON_ROOT  Node with a skinned mesh is not root. Parent transforms will not affect a skinned mesh. /nodes/230
Any one help me to fix this issue!!

The error seems to clearly point out some issues: have you resolved those, or at least looked into them?

I tried may ways, but still getting same issue

The NODE_SKINNED_MESH_NON_ROOT message is safe to ignore.  The glTF Validator flags this as a "warning", not an "error" (see ISSUES.md#L65), so your glTF export still passes validation even with this message on it.
The root cause is that Blender always makes the target object a child of the armature controlling it, as a design choice, and in glTF that places the skinned mesh down below the root level, which is (for technical reasons) considered a very minor inefficiency for realtime rendering engines.  In glTF, the skinned mesh gets 100% of its position from the set of bones, so there's no use placing the skinned mesh in some transformed node or somewhere deep in the scene hierarchy.  But in Blender, the bones may be less than 100% and the object's position in the node hierarchy comes into play.  The glTF exporter in Blender accounts for this disparity (by creating a new root bone if needed) but ends up placing the skinned mesh not at the root level.  Someday this may get fixed in #1626, but it's not hurting anyone and the solution itself could introduce new problems, so it's not high priority.
In any case, it's safe to ignore NODE_SKINNED_MESH_NON_ROOT.  Blender exports with armatures will always give you that message, and it doesn't mean the model is broken.
